# Closed form expression for Integral of exponential function

Tags: integration, exponential-function

How to compute the following integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{n_0}^{\infty} \exp(- c x^\lambda) dx,
\end{equation}

when $0 < \lambda \leq 1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp\Big(-c~x^\lambda\Big)~dx=\frac{\bigg(\dfrac1\lambda\bigg)!}{\sqrt[\lambda]c}~,~$ see [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more information. But since

your lower integration limit is $n_0$ instead of $0$, you will have to use the [incomplete $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

One can also write it as $~\dfrac n\lambda\cdot\text{E}\bigg(1-\dfrac1\lambda~,~c~n^\lambda\bigg),~$ see [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The computer algebra system maxima tells us:
$$
\int \exp\left(-c\,x^\lambda\right) dx = -\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\lambda},c\,x^\lambda\right)}{\lambda\,c^\frac{1}{\lambda}}
$$
Where $\Gamma\left(s,x\right)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function, so:
$$
\int_{n_{0}}^\infty \exp\left(-c\,x^\lambda\right) dx = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\lambda},c\,x^\lambda\right)}{\lambda\,c^\frac{1}{\lambda}}+\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\lambda},c\,n_0^\lambda\right)}{\lambda\,c^\frac{1}{\lambda}} = \dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\lambda},c\,n_0^\lambda\right)}{\lambda\,c^\frac{1}{\lambda}}
$$

Comment: Why the minus sign?

Comment: @grdgfgr the minus sign at the end is wrong because there is one missing in the beginning - thank you!